IdentityServer4 unable to logout
I've created my Identity server from IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI library. Currently using IdentityServer4(4.1.2) version. And also I have a react SPA application which using axa-fr/react-oidc package to deal things with both identity server and react app.
Couple days ago, I noticed that when I click logout button in my react app which calls logout function of axa-fr/react-oidc library. It does show me a page which claims I logged out successfully. But when I call the main page of react app again, I am logging in without authentication...
My identity server config as follows;
     new()
 {
     ClientId = "reactapp-local",
     ClientName = "App UI",
     AllowedGrantTypes = {GrantType.AuthorizationCode, GrantType.ResourceOwnerPassword},
     AllowedScopes = { "openid", "profile","app"},
     ClientUri="http://localhost:3000",
     RedirectUris={ "http://localhost:3000/authentication/callback" },
     PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "http://localhost:3000/authentication/signout-callback-oidc" }, // Add this
     AllowedCorsOrigins={ "http://localhost:3000" },
     RequirePkce=true,
     RequireClientSecret=false,
     AccessTokenLifetime=2678400,
     UserSsoLifetime=2678400,
     ClientSecrets ={new Secret("memoli".Sha256())},
     AllowOfflineAccess=true,
     Description="app",
     LogoUri="https://somedomain.com:5022/img/products/logo-app.png",
     Properties=PropertiesService.GetAppProperties()
 },

axa-fr/react-oidc client configuration;
const dev = {
  client_id: 'reactapp-local',
  redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/authentication/callback',
  silent_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/authentication/silent-callback',
  scope: 'openid profile app',
  post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000/authentication/signout-callback-oidc', // Ensure this matches IdentityServer
  authority: 'http://localhost:34801',
  refresh_time_before_tokens_expiration_in_second: 40,
  service_worker_relative_url: '/OidcServiceWorker.js',
  service_worker_only: false,
  token_renew_mode: TokenRenewMode.access_token_invalid,
  demonstrating_proof_of_possession: false,
  client_secret: 'safafasasf+afasfasfafasf/pe/Unols=',
};

From the output tab of visual studio, I see the logs as follow;
info: IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware[0]
﻿      Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint for /connect/endsession/callback
﻿info: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.EndSessionCallbackEndpoint[0]
﻿      Successful signout callback.

I've done a extensive research but unable to find what causes this problem :/
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Don't you have one session with IdentityServer and one session cookie with the react application? Ensure that both are deleted in the browser when you signout. Also, using HTTPS everwhere is recomended, otherwise some cookies will be rejected.

First of all, thank you for your comment. I noticed that idsrv and idsrv.session remain the same. The logout method did not delete cookies. I think I need to check why cookies aren't deleted. @ToreNestenius

Glad I can be of assistance! Perhaps the SignOutASync in the account/logout is not called on the Account page? I would lower the log level and check the logs in IdentityServer.

There is this line on Logout function if (User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true) which never turns true. Under that if block, it calls HttpContext.SignOutAsnyc and raises event. I wonder why it never turns true. Its because I tested that when you call able to get these two lines, logout works. It is from Quickstart template of IdentityServer4. @ToreNestenius

Could be that the cookies are blocked for various reasons if you use HTTP, I blogged about how to diagnose cookie problems here https://nestenius.se/net/debugging-cookie-problems/

It is same with https, not deleting those cookies.. I still suspect something wront with the configuration and maybe logout page itself. I am stuck. lol @ToreNestenius Thank you for your help again.

PErhaps paste a copy of your configuration in the startup/program or hostextensions.class  ( like AddAuthentication....)

I would also create a sample ASP.NET core client appliction instead of React, and compare the logout request to IdentityServer and see if that works or not.

I've tested with clean IdentityServer4 quickstart project. And It works as expected. I guess something wrong with my configurations or something. I'll let you to know the results @ToreNestenius

Great! See my blog for most posts and facts about identityserver and openid connect in general.

@ToreNestenius. I answered my own question, the problem turned out to be something unrelated. Thank you again.

I am answering my own question for people who would face the same issue in future. It is not related about IdentityServer4 configurations or axa-fr/react-oidc library.
Error caused from calling app.UseIdentityServer() in wrong order. I can't tell why this happens but if you call anything before app.UseIdentityServer() it causes this kind of  weird problem.
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseIdentityServer(); ->Call this first. 
app.UseStaticFiles();

